# HAProxy Routing Based On Url

Tags: redirect, haproxy

Scenario:   if url is `http://domain`   or `http://domain/web`  then there should not be a redirect.  For anything else, say `http://domain/abc` or `http://domain/xyz`, there should be a redirect to `http://domain2`.

This is what I tried and but it only works for `http://domain/web`.  If the url is `http://domain`, it still redirects to `http://domain2`.

```
acl is_root path -i
acl missing_slash path_reg ^/*/[^/]*$$  
acl isweb path_beg /web
http-request set-header X-Location-Path %[capture.req.uri] if  !isweb !is_root !missing_slash
http-request replace-header X-Location-Path [^/]+/(.*) \1 if  !isweb !is_root !missing_slash
http-request redirect code 301 location https://www.domain2.com%[hdr(X-Location-Path)] if  !isweb !is_root !missing_slash
```

Answer (score 0):

Match string `/`.

```
acl is_root path -m str /
```

The request URI can never actually be an empty string in HTTP.  The browser will always send `GET / HTTP/1.1` whether or not the address bar actually shows the `/` after the hostname.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same outcome after this change

Comment: Your `missing_slash` test seems invalid.  Not sure what you are trying to do with that, but `*` in a regex means "zero or more occurrences" so this appears to match `/` preventing the other rule from taking effect.  You may have intended `path_reg [^/]$` -- path does not end with a slash -- or `path_reg ^/.+/[^/]+$`.  Please explain what that pattern is supposed to match against.

Comment: My regex is very poor.  This is what I want to find out... if a url is like this www.mydomain.com     or www.mydomain.com/web.  Other than these two conditions, redirect will be to domain2.

Comment: Remove the `!missing_slash` test from all three tests.  Depending on your HAProxy version, this process is much simpler than your approach is making it.  Please mention the version (`haproxy -v`).

Comment: HAProxy version 1.6.3.  I will try it. So far I have tried many different things with no success. Everything except finding if the user has entered www.domain.com only has worked.